# need help minus value from database column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to minus value in database column from textbox I got error an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected

```
  cn.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
  command.Connection = cn;

  command.CommandText = "select * from class where  quanitity - '"+Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)+"'";
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  cn.Close();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Update the value in the database or find a record?

Comment: You have a WHERE clause with no way to evaluate the expression. `WHERE quantity - <some value>` is not going to generate a boolean condition.

Comment: Never concat sql from text boxes it leaves you wide open to sql injection.  Use parameters instead.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: IAM TRYING to minus value in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not minus value to column.you want like this

```
        command.CommandText = "update class set quanitity = quanitity - "+Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely work

```
command.CommandText = string.Format("update class set quanitity= quanitity - {0}",Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a value to compare your two numbers to. You are subtracting your TextBox10 value from quantity, but what result set do you want to see after subtracting the value? There needs to be a comparison somewhere to the right of your WHERE.

```
command.CommandText = "select (quantity - "+Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)+") from class ;
```

Comment: when i click the button it subtract the value from the database

Comment: Added a select statement. This will return quantity minus the TextBox amount.

Comment: give me 13 error in in from table name iwrite the table name

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you [SQL Injection alert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)..Do not Concatenate string it's wide open for sql injection alert.So use parameterized query

```
command.CommandText = "select * from class where  quanitity -@txtbox10";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtbox10", Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i will make this textbox accept numbers only so how can make sql injection ;)